# mypy - unable to use BufferedIOBase in type signature

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have the following code

```
import io

def reader(byte_stream: io.BufferedIOBase):
    ...

reader(open("./README.md", "rb"))
```

When I run this file through `mypy`, I get the following type error:

```
subclass.py:6:8: error: Argument 1 to "reader" has incompatible type "BinaryIO"; expected "BufferedIOBase"  [arg-type]
    reader(open("./README.md", "rb"))
           ^
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This should not be an error though, as `BinaryIO` inherits from `BufferedIOBase`, which I have verified here:

```
isinstance(open("./README.md", "rb"), io.BufferedIOBase)  # True
```

So, what is wrong with my type signature?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly *why* the class is incompatible with the type hint, but the easy fix is to use the type hint in your signature. (It's even documented as representing the type of values returned by `open`.)

```
def reader(byte_stream: typing.BinaryIO):
    ...
```